# Restrict purchasing in GCP Marketplace

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to restrict users from purchasing trial and paid for apps, such as Anthos, in GCP Marketplace? I can't find any policies that can prevent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: dont give these users neither `Editor` nor `Owner` nor `Billing Account Administrator` roles.

More precisely dont give them these permissions :

- `consumerprocurement.freeTrials.create` available within `Consumer Procurement Entitlement Manager`, `Editor` and `Owner` roles
- `consumerprocurement.orders.place` available within `Consumer Procurement Order Administrator`, `Billing Account Administrator`, `Editor` and `Owner` roles

You can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/access-control) more details about managing access controls for Cloud Marketplace with IAM.